# chat/messaging PHP foreach loop confusion

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach, chat, messaging

I'm trying to set up a messaging system where a user's messages are displayed in chronological order. I'd like to have the user's replies to a given message be listed directly below the message they replied to.

Basically I was thinking I need the following 5 variables: `user_id`, `recipient_id`, `message_id`, `reply_id`, and `message`.

Can someone offer a basic PHP solution for this? I'd assume all it will take is some `foreach` loops and if, else statements, I just can come up with solution.

Here's what I have so far which only echos the user's replies and not their messages, nor nested in within their messages:

```
<?php foreach($messages as $message)
{
    $msg_id=$message->message_id;
    $rply_id=$message->reply_id;
    if($msg_id=$rply_id)
    {
        echo $message->message;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Assuming these are stored in objects or variables, I'd probably take the recursive method approach. Begin with a general list of messages, then have it expand out any and all replies relating to that message through recursion.

Comment: What does your object look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do this:

### Format the data pulled from the database into a basic id-indexed array and a foreign-key-indexed array

- Pull all messages from the database that are NOT replies, order by date.
- Index the resulting array by message id.
- Pull all messages from the database that are replies, order by date.
- Loop over the replies, putting them into a new, multidimentional array, grouped by reply_id.

### Formatting of output

Foreach loop over non-reply messages:

- Display each message.
- Pull the id of each message and check whether it is a key in the replies array.
- If it is present in the replies array...

  - Foreach loop to display each reply message that is present.

End of message foreach loop.